# Embed SWF file in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, flash

I'm developing extensions for Chrome, Safari and Firefox, and I need to add SWF file in my extension. I want to show it on a page. I read in documentation that I can store media files in Chrome and Safari extension.

Can I do the same with Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a Firefox extension can also contain any files you like. But you probably meant to ask: "Can I get a URL of a file in my extension that will be usable on a web page?" If you are using the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) then it is simply:

```js
var self = require("self");
var url = self.data.url("file.swf");
```

In a classic add-on it is slightly more complicated - `chrome://` URLs normally cannot be used by web pages, for security reasons. You can however [specify the `contentaccessible` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#contentaccessible) for your namespace in `chrome.manifest`, e.g.:

```
content myextension chrome/content/ contentaccessible=yes
```

Then web pages will be able to use `chrome://myextension/content/file.swf`. The other option would be to [register a `resource://` namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#resource), these are always accessible from web pages.